# Dynamically changing schema for different tenants in multi-tenant asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, schema, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2014, multi-tenant

We are developing ASP.NET MVC based multi-tenant application using SQL server as a database. To connect database Entity Framework database first approach has been used. We are following [Shared Database, Separate Schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) approach. Once a new tenant will register in the application a seprate schema would be created with ALMOST same set of tables, and they can access their own data. It will require to change schema dynamically per tenant, how it can be achieved in EntityFramework database first development environment so that each tenant will have access to their own schema and its tables?